# Феномен появления новой конструкции "Пойду погуляю", в условиях существования синонимичных конструкций "Пойду погулять"/"Пойду и погуляю"

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология

Рассмотрим относительно новую конструкцию: **пойду + глагол в той же форме**.
Почему эта конструкция устоялась если она не отличается от альтернативных? А если отличается то чем?

В большинстве примеров, верны равенства типа:

> Пойду поиграю с ним = Пойду поиграть с ним = Пойду и поиграю с ним.

Отсюда как будто следует, что это конструкция синонимична остальным и оснований для её становления нет.
Но она твердо вошла в современный русский язык, почему?

Comment: Для справки: *"Я пойду погуляю, Ахъ! Люли, люли, погуляю!"* — это из наверняка известной Вам песни "Во поле берёза стояла". Точная датировка этой песни неизвестна, но считается, что появилась она намного раньше 1790 г., когда была впервые напечатана.

Comment: А что насчет запятой в песне 1790? Была ли она там или нет хоть когда-нибудь? Насчет синонимии, ну хорошо, положим обстоятельство цели мы отвергли как синонимию и выбросили в мусорное ведро. Но остается ведь еще синонимия с Пойду и погуляю. И по ссылке об этом ничего не говорится

Comment: Оригинального издания сборника 1790 г. я не видел, но видел второе издание того же сборника, которое вышло в 1806 г. Посмотрите сами [здесь](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Ic1gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT124&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%83+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj22rrD86_uAhXcisMKHVDsBroQ6AEwBHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%22&f=false).

Comment: @JKlen Вот это да! Спасибо! А я по наивности думал, что гугло-книги начинаются с XIX в.

Comment: @JKlen  *и двумя однородными сказуемыми* - это не два однородных сказуемых. "Пойду" выступает здесь в роли побудительного наклонения, близкой к модальной,

Comment: пойду погуляю и покормлю голубей = пойду погулять и покормлю голубей. На мой взгляд полная синонимия. Не всегда есть синонимия с двумя вариантами сразу(обстоятельство цели и однородные сказуемые), но похоже что всегда с одним из этих двух. По-хорошему надо найти случай когда синонимии нет ни с одним из двух вариантов. Тогда вопросы отпадут. Я думаю что искать его надо не с пойду погуляю, а с пойду что-то ещё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное, в чем автор уверенно ошибается - так это в том, что формы с *"пойду/пойдем" могут быть всегда адекватно заменены на инфинитивные конструкции.* Стоит поставить основной глагол в совершенный вид - и вся идея пропадает.

"Пойдём поговорим" - как минимум предпочтительнее "пойдем поговорить", да и смысл явно другой. В первом случае имеет место особый способ выражения повелительного наклонения (точнее бы сказать - побудительного, но в русской грамматике их не принято различать).

Вот, собственно, и все.
Автор (простите, не поворачивается язык обращаться по номеру) напутал с семантикой, остальное - следствие этого.

Comment: Ну, наконец-то, я признаться, с самого начала знал о примере пойду + совершенный вид. Но хотел чтобы мне все "объяснили" по полочкам :)

Comment: Дело не только и не столько в совершенном виде, сколько  во множественном числе. Для ед. числа повелительное наклонение не так легко прочувствовать без некоторой филологической подготовки.

Comment: Дело не повелительном наклонении, здесь вы вольны ставить любое другое. Пример у меня был: пойду обыграю его

Comment: @user190920 Простите, дискутировать не имею возможности.

Comment: Вот вы тоже интересный вопрос подняли, я думал что это не проблема. Можно ли избавиться от повелительного наклонения? Скажем "возьму и сделаю" спокойно переходит в "взял и сделал". А что насчет "Он пошел погулял" ?? Корректна ли такая фраза???

Comment: @user19092 Почитайте наконец правила. Комментарии не предназначены для дискуссий.

Comment: Ну, тогда назовем это уточнением вашего ответа, а не дискуссией.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118821/discussion-between-behemothus-and-user190920).

Answer (score 0):

В древнерусском было вроде достигательное наклонение/супин. Глагол движения + инфинитив, значение цели. Похоже, потребность в нем осталась до сих пор, и подспудно его жизнь продолжается и в наше время в разговорной речи вот в таких, несколько измененных, формах: пойду поем, пойду посплю, пойду погуляю и т.п. Формы с инфинитивом в роли обстоятельства больше распространены в литературном языке.
Пойду и погуляю - это из другой оперы, конечно же, это по смыслу сильно отличается от первых двух примеров.

Comment: Супин был, только от строился совсем не так и функцию имел другую.Здесь у нас пойду вообще не имеет смысла глагола движения. Это не достигательное наклонение, а скорее побудительное..

Comment: Возможно! А побудительное разве не обращено всегда к другим лицам? Можно попробовать заменить "пойду" в "пойду погуляю" на другое слово с сохранением того же смысла. На мой взгляд, получится подобрать разве что слово со значением времени - "а сейчас я погуляю". Видно, что есть твердое намерение выполнить намеченное действие. Смысл глагола движения, по-моему, тоже есть: ухожу отсюда, буду заниматься другим делом. "Пойду поработаю!" - так мы оповещаем окружающих о своих намерениях или говорим сами себе, и при этом меняется наша дислокация. Нельзя так сказать и остаться на том же месте.

Comment: В русской грамматике его нет, поэтому оно может быть обращено к кому угодно. ))) Я , конечно, допустил известную вольность, назвав эту форму побудительным наклонением, но не думал, что это введет кого-то в заблуждение.

Comment: И, кстати говоря, нормативная форма для "побудительного" наклонения (*Пусть+глагол*) допускает 1 лицо: *[Бобчинский:] Уж не мешайте, пусть я расскажу.* ... АГ-80 http://www.rusgram.narod.ru/1937-1951.html  Но я не об этом, как вы, надеюсь, поняли.

Comment: Ну, я ведь не знаю, чего я еще не знаю, не так много умных книжек я прочитала - а среди этих незнаний вполне может оказаться и что-то подобное "побудительному наклонению", так что я честно пытаюсь понять, что Вы имеете в виду, и рассуждаю в силу своего понимания.)  А как по-Вашему, "пусть я расскажу" насколько нормально звучит? Как по мне, так только какие-нибудь бобчинские так и могут высказываться, и то один раз за всю литературу. Это просьба к окружающим, скорее... Давайте (,) я расскажу!  Не знаю, нужна ли здесь запятая.

Comment: Так я вообще книжек не читал.  Давайте вернемся к теме, ок?

Comment: Я кажется нашел полную синонимию. пойду погуляю= погуляю-ка. пойду обыграю его = обыграю-ка его. Пойдем поговорим = поговорим-ка!

Comment: По смыслу почти полностью подходит. И все же место действия при "-ка" не меняется. А "пойдем поговорим" - люди же реально куда-то перемещаются?

Comment: Да, перемещение это отголосок семантики "пойду". И эта семантика в большинстве случаев лишняя. Мне например никогда не нравилась тавтологичность: Пойду погуляю, Пойду побегаю, Пойдем выйдем, итп. Но в случае с пойдем поговорим, эта семантика наоборот в тему.

Comment: Для меня такое "пойду" означает, что собеседник устал разговаривать и хочет выйти из беседы. Оно на самом деле означает "ухожу, потому что есть важное дело". Вот пример: "Пойду расскажу  коту/ бабушкам у подъезда/ всем и т.п. Тут ощущается даже некая недоброжелательность. Пойду гулять - звучит нейтрально, пойду погуляю - более фамильярно, так скорее разговаривают с близкими.

Comment: "Пойду гулять" это ведь обычное будущее время, оно может случиться и через три года. А пойду погуляю это ближайшее будущее. Так что да, выходить из беседы лучше с помощью ближайшего будущего, а не просто будущего "пойду гулять". А кто что думает насчет "пойду погуляю" в прошедшем времени?

Comment: Навеяло старый анекдот: "Решили послать сходить купить выпить."  В прошедшем времени тоже возможно подобное: "Я сходил купил книг в роту и подарки для больных". (с) Форма глагола словно дублируется, и возможно такое с ограниченным количеством слов.

Comment: "Сходил купил","Сбегал купил","съезжу погуляю" не пойму это другая конструкция, или та же самая? Похоже что та же.  Вроде не однородные сказуемые. То есть получается А вот "пошел обыграл" как-то не звучит в отличии от "взял и обыграл".

Comment: Взял и обыграл - это точно сильно отличается. На частицу больше похоже. А "сходил купил" - все еще сохраняется значение движения.