# Есть ли смысловое различие между фразами: "Иди гуляй" и "Иди гулять", какой вариант правильнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли смысловое различие между фразами: "Иди гуляй" и "Иди гулять", какой вариант правильнее?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463242/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Иди гулять" имеет *буквальный* смысл, например, при обращении к ребёнку.

"Иди гуляй" - это фамильярная, грубоватая форма отказа в чём-то (напр. в просьбе дать денег, чтобы опохмелиться) или даже попытка прогнать (смягчённое "иди отсюда").